# Как настроить хостинг MySQL так, чтобы все поля имели default "value"?

Tags: mysql, хостинг, default

Как настроить хостинг MySQL так, чтобы все поля имели `default value = 0`?

Comment: Никак. MySQL делает строго то, что сказано. Нет DEFAULT - значит, и не должно быть.

Comment: Указать всем полям нужное дефолтное значение. Конструкции для задания сразу всем полям значения нет